# Create dar package using XL deploy api instead of "Package with Xl Deploy" VSTS task

Tags: batch-file, azure-devops, xl-deploy

"Package with Xl Deploy" VSTS task exist that allow us to create a .Dar file.
We want to achieve same but by using VSTS Command Line task and using command in it something like :
curl -u :http://localhost:4516/deployit/repository/ci// -d@data.xml

Answer (score 0):

Examples can be found on the [docs](https://docs.xebialabs.com/xl-deploy/how-to/xl-deploy-sample-rest-calls.html) and the detailed properties for a `udm.Version` can be found [here](https://docs.xebialabs.com/xl-deploy/8.2.x/udmcireference.html#udmversion)